# PHP - MySQL: Get rows from table where date between two dates

Tags: php, mysql

I've got a problem with mysql getting the rows between two dates.

The column is `res_birthday (VARCHAR)` and the date looks like `30.11.1970`.

Now I have to get customers whose birthdays are between `01.01.` and `10.01.`, the year doesn't matter.

I've tried many solutions with:

```
STR_TO_DATE(`res_birthday`, '%d.%m')
```

but I cannot compare it to the start and end date.

Any idea how I can solve this?

### Edit:

Here is some code with the solutions mentioned below, but it does not work.

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `jtmpl2_chronoforms_data_test_reservierung` WHERE MONTH(STR_TO_DATE(`res_birthday`, '%d.%m.%y')) = 5 AND DAYOFMONTH(STR_TO_DATE(`res_birthday`, '%d.%m.%y')) = 10;");

     while($info = mysql_fetch_array( $query )) 



    function createCodeOrg($query){
     while($info = mysql_fetch_array( $query )) 
    { 
        $code = '<tr>
                            <td>'.$info['res_anrede'].'</td>
                        <td>'.ucfirst($info['res_vorname']).'</td>
                        <td>'.ucfirst($info['res_nachname']).'</td>
                        <td>'.ucfirst($info['res_strasse_hnr']).'</td>      
                        <td>'.$info['res_plz'].'</td>               
                        <td>'.ucfirst($info['res_ort']).'</td>
                        <td>'.$info['res_geburtstag'].'</td>    
                        <td><a href="mailto:'.$info['res_email'].'">'.$info['res_email'].'</a></td>                 

                      </tr>';

    echo $code;
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select * from your_table
where MONTH(STR_TO_DATE(res_birthday, '%d.%m.%Y')) = 1
and DAYOFMONTH(STR_TO_DATE(res_birthday, '%d.%m.%Y')) between 1 and 10
```

### [SQLFiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/5ee64/3)

Comment: I've tried: 
SELECT * FROM `jtmpl2_chronoforms_data_test_reservierung` WHERE MONTH(STR_TO_DATE(`res_birthday`, '%d.%m.%y')) = 5 AND DAYOFMONTH(STR_TO_DATE(`res_birthday`, '%d.%m.%y')) between 1 and 30;

but it doesn't work.

Comment: It doesnt fetch any rows and gives me a error on mysql_fetch_array().

Comment: @EugenKochtyrew Then show your code, maybe we could help. Disclaimer: don't use `mysql_*` functions anymore, they are deprecated. See [Why shouldn't I use mysql_* functions in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php) for details.

Comment: I've changed my form and code a little bit, now it works with your solution. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is you're storing dates as varchars. This removes the ability of the DB to what it could automatically if you'd been using `DATE` or `DATETIME` fields:

```
SELECT ...
FROM ...
WHERE res_birthday BETWEEN 'yyyy-mm-dd' AND 'yyyy-mm-dd'
```

Convert your fields now, and your problem essentially goes away.

Comment: -1 "*I have to get the customers wich birthday is between 01.01. and 10.01., the year doesn't matter.*"

Comment: My answer still holds. Converting to native date/datetime will make this FAR easier.

Comment: Well, the database won't be able to do anything "automatically": you certainly cannot use `BETWEEN` in the manner shown and will need to apply further manipulations to extract day and month parts.

Answer (score -1):

I believe this is what you are looking for:

```
SELECT column_name(s)
FROM table_name
WHERE column_name BETWEEN value1 AND value2;
```

Source: http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_between.asp

Comment: Don't recommend w3schools.com as a reference. It's full of errors, see http://w3fools.com.

Comment: I agree, and normally I wouldn't use it as a reference. In this case however, this article is accurate. I see no harm in referencing this particular article.

Comment: Well, someone might think that other stuff on that side is ok, which it isn't.

Comment: You'd think that after all the bad publicity that W3schools has been getting (for years), they would update their website in order to reflect the proper usage etc. @MarcelKorpel

Comment: @Fred-ii- Well, there used to be a list of several errors on w3fools.com with corrected stuff striked through. The last time I saw it I believe about 40% of the errors mentioned there were corrected.

Comment: I'm just glad I'm not the one that built their Website. Had I built it, and as we say around here *"I'll never get work in this town again."* @MarcelKorpel